# Form won't call javascript function when I press enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

```
<form id="search" onSubmit="go()">
    <input autofocus autocomplete="off" type="text" class="searchbar" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search Keywords: search, navigate, weather" required>
    <input type="button" value="Go" class="go" id="go" onclick="go()">
</form>
```

I have the function in an external javascript document that I have sourced at the bottom of my webpage, the function works when I click the submit button, just not when I hit enter.

My go function:

```
function go() {
var input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;
var words = input.split(" ");
var wordsLength = words.length;
var searchWords = '';

if(words[0] == 'search' || words[0] == 'Search') {
    for(var x = 1; x < wordsLength; x++) {
        searchWords += words[x];
        if(x == wordsLength-1) {
        } else {
            searchWords += '+';
        }
    }
    window.location.replace("http://www.google.com/#q=" + searchWords);
} else if(words[0] == 'navigate' || words[0] == 'Navigate') {
    for(var x = 1; x < wordsLength; x++) {
        searchWords += words[x];
        if(x == wordsLength-1) {
        } else {
            searchWords += '+';
        }
    }
    window.location.replace("http://www.google.com/maps/place/" + searchWords);
}
}
```

Comment: change input type button to "submit" and  check.

Comment: That didn't work either

Comment: can you pls explain your go function ?

Comment: call go function on form keypress event or textbox keypress evetnt.on key press you will get key code . if keycode 13 then submit form.check answer given by @amy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
<input type="button" value="Go" class="go" id="go" onclick="go()">
```

to

```
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: I'm affraid that didn't do it : /

Comment: Your solution would work not because you changed to 'submit' but because you removed the id

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="search" onsubmit="go()">
    <input autofocus autocomplete="off" type="text" class="searchbar" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search Keywords: search, navigate, weather" required>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your id of the button and the function name is same change one of those.

```
<form id="search" onSubmit="go()">
     <input autofocus autocomplete="off" type="text" class="searchbar" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search Keywords: search, navigate, weather" required>
     <input type="button" value="Go" class="go" id="_go" onclick="go()">
</form>
```

Comment: that doesn't change anything, Id's and classes can have the same name you just reference them differently

Comment: I am not talking about class but onclick method and id have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery solution.

```
<form id="search">
    <input autofocus autocomplete="off" type="text" class="searchbar" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search Keywords: search, navigate, weather" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

On Form Submit call `go()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').submit(function() {
        //Add code from go() or just call go()
    });
});
```

**UPDATE** :

```
<form id="search" onSubmit="go()">
    <input autofocus autocomplete="off" type="text" class="searchbar" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search Keywords: search, navigate, weather" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Jquery Part.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#searchbar').live("keypress", function(e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you add the `go()` function in question.

Comment: the go function has been added, but it does work when I click on the submit button so I don't think that it is the issue

Comment: that didn't work either, I think it might be because the page I'm making is a new tab page and google chrome might be overriding it or something...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is working.

**HTML**

```
<form id="search" onSubmit="return false">
    <input autofocus autocomplete="off" type="text" class="searchbar" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search Keywords: search, navigate, weather" required>
    <input type="button" value="Go" class="go" id="go">
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('form').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    go($('#searchbar').val());
    $('form#search_form').submit();
    return false;  
  }
});

function go(keyword){
    alert('Your search keyword is [' + keyword + ']');
}
```

**[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zbo1fLow/)**